# Why does $a_0$ annihilate the vacuum states $|0\rangle$?

Tags: hilbert-space, operators, momentum, string-theory, vacuum

In the string theory the ladder operator were somewhat followed from the QFT.
However, the definition of the $a_0\sim p^\mu$, defined from the zero mode expansion of $X^\mu$ directly, were not quite the same as the rising and the lowering operator in the QFT. There does not seem to be an obvious reason of why $a_0|0\rangle=0$.

In a related post [Why does the QCD vacuum have zero momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228143/why-does-the-qcd-vacuum-have-zero-momentum) this was explained from the Poincaré invariant.
But in the string theory, the momentum operator $P = L_0-\bar L_0\sim a_0^2 -\bar a_0^2$,
the annihilation condition was not constrained to $a_0$ or $\bar a_0$ individually.

Why does $a_0$ annihilate the vacuum states $|0\rangle$? Is it a convention or was there some constrains stated that $a_0|0\rangle$ must be true?